# Performance messurement on Windows Phone app (ARM)

Tags: c#, performance, windows-phone, arm

I want to create a tool for my app performance measurement, something that I can put in sort of section and it will take a timestamp at the beginning and at the end, and then it will write to log the time delta.

However I don't want this functionality in my Production version (I want those measurements to be excluded from the compilation on Production) - I want them only on Debug mode...

I have looked at several AOT libraries, such as Postsharp , but they cost money and also most of them (including PostSharp) don't supports ARM architecture.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I came with something like this, which is a singletone when you are not in debug and normal instantse when you are:
Usage:

```
using(PerfMesureHandler.Get("Something to meassure")))
{
    //Code to measure
}
```

Code:

```
    public class PerfMesureHandler: IDisposable
        {
            private PerfMesureHandler(string topic, string methodName , int lineNumber )
            {
    #if DEBUG
                _methodName = methodName;
                _lineNumber = lineNumber;
                _topic = topic;   
                _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
                _stopwatch.Start();
    #endif
            }

            private string _topic;
            private static PerfMesureHandler_singleton;
            private Stopwatch _stopwatch;
            private int _lineNumber;
            private string _methodName;


            public static PerfMesureHandler Start(string topic, [CallerMemberName] string methodName = "", [CallerLineNumber] int lineNumber = 0)
            {
                PerfMesureHandler= null;
    #if DEBUG
                result = new PerfMesureHandler(topic, methodName, lineNumber);
    #else
                if (_singleton == null)
                {
                    _singleton = new PerfMesureHandler(topic, methodName, lineNumber);
                }
                result = _singleton;       
    #endif
                return result;
            }

        public void Dispose()
        {
#if DEBUG
            _stopwatch.Stop();
            //Write to log...
            string msg = $"topic: {_topic}, time:  {_stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}, method: {_methodName}, line: {_lineNumber}";
            Console.WriteLine(msg)
#endif
        }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly you are asking. If you can build your own class for this task, do it. If you need to exclude logging for release version - use this as an example:

This is class for performance measurement

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class PerfLibTest
    {
#if DEBUG
        private DateTime dtStarted;
#endif

        public void StartIt()
        {
#if DEBUG
            dtStarted = DateTime.Now;
#endif
        }

        public void StopAndLogIt()
        {
#if DEBUG
            //write somewhere (DateTime.Now-dtStarted).TotalMilliseconds
#endif
        }

    }
}
```

and this is class which funct5ion will me measured:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class CLassToTest
    {
        public void DoSomeJob()
        {
            PerfLibTest pf = new PerfLibTest();
            pf.StartIt();

            // do some job

            pf.StopAndLogIt();
        }
    }
}
```

Conditional

```
#if DEBUG
```

will helps you to exclude measurements from RELEASE version.

Comment: Sure, but one of the things that I want to avoid is the creation of many unused instances, so what I've done eventually is something similar to your implementation, only when I am not in debug  - I am using it as singletone without implementation... :) Thank you for your answer

Comment: Also I think that Stopwatch is better solution then DateTime for performance measurement...

Comment: Sure you can use StopWatch. I just created simple classes to show the idea.